# scanf() (and cin) statements skipped when using gcc

Tags: gcc, scanf

When multiple `scanf()` statements are encountered in the code, then, except the first `scanf()` statement, all others are skipped, that is, there is no prompt for input for those `scanf()` statements when the code is run.

I have a tried a few suggestions. For eg, use of `flushall()` was suggested on some site, but that gives a compilation error.

Any help greatly appreciated.

[The code was added as [an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2787189/256431).]

Comment: Add a quick example with it failing?

Comment: May be easier to help with<br><hr>
1) The code<br>
2) The user input

Answer (score 3):

Check the return value of scanf()!

From the man page:
"scanf returns the number of input items assigned, which can be  fewer  than  provided  for,  or even zero, in the event of a matching failure.  Zero indicates that, while there was input available, no conversions were assigned;  typically  this  is  due  to  an invalid input character, such as an alphabetic character for a ‘%d’ conversion.  The value EOF is returned if an input failure occurs before any conversion such  as  an  end-of-file occurs.  If  an error or end-of-file occurs after conversion has begun, the number of conversions which were successfully completed is returned."

Answer (score 2):

An example of the code **and** input would definitely improve our ability to help you with your specific problem as there are a lot of potential situations that can cause the problem.

Example (I can think of quickly):

- The format string does not match the next character on the input stream. The scanf is thus not reading anything.
- The stdin input buffer is only flushed when full or return is encountered.
- The input from 1 line of typing may be used by multiple scanf statements. Subsequent scanf statements pick up where the last on left off. Thus the program does not stop for user input.
- The %s behaves differently on scanf and printf
  printf it prints a whole string.
  scanf it read **ONE** space separated word

Answer (score 0):

I've always thought scanf() was dangerous as it can leave your input streams in an indeterminate state.

I prefer to use other (safer) commands to bring in a string (fgets and such) then use sscanf to process it. Then you can always back up to the start of the string and restart.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like some conversion issue. It may be that a %s conversion never ends or   you specify a character which is never input or something like this. I suggest the following:
a. Try something like:
    int a=0;
    int b=0;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    scanf("%d", &b);
    printf("a=%d, b=%d\n", a, b);
If this works, try augmenting the conversions, to see which one causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The Code simple, as it is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
long int z,s,n,i,j,m,x;
scanf("%ld ",&z);
for(i=0; i<z; i++)
  {
  scanf("%ld",&s); n=0;
  for (j=0; j<s; j++) { scanf("%ld",&m); n+=m; }
  x=n+s-1;
  printf("%ld\n",n);
  }
return 0;
}
```

Compilation:

```
D:\edycja>gcc WSEGA.c -o WSEGA.exe -Wall

D:\edycja>WSEGA.exe

D:\edycja> [Where was the program!?]
```

Answer (score 0):

always use ""fflush(stdin);"" before any "scanf();" statement because unless and until u don't clear the standard input stream scanf statement will read the already present value in std i/p.

Answer (score 0):

I'm fairly new to coding, but I had this problem before and learned in class that it's better not to use fflush before each scanf.
Instead put a space inside the scanf before the format specifier (that's the "%d" or "%c% that you see).

Example of what will skip:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char char1, char2;
    
    scanf("%c", &char1);
    scanf("%c", &char2);
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

This would read char1, but it would skip char2. (Actually, the return character you type after char1 would be read as char2.)
In order to prevent this, put a space like in the next example.

Example of what won't skip:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    char char1, char2;
    
    scanf(" %c", &char1);
    scanf(" %c", &char2);
    
    
    return 0;
}
```

In this example, you only need the space for the second scanf, but I put it for both just in case because I might write something else or change the code, and it makes it easier to already have it there.

Hopefully that helps.